# Simple Highlighting Function is very slow on larger files

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, highlight

I have a function which highlights Keywords in a `RichTextBox`, it is working perfectly fine on small texts, but it is very slow on larger texts.

Which lines are causing the problem and what can I improve to speed it up?

```cs
private void menu_EnableHighlighting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    newRichBox.SelectAll();
    TextPointer position = newRichBox.Document.ContentStart;
    List<TextRange> ranges = new List<TextRange>();
    while (position != null)
    {
        if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            string text = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            var matchs = Regex.Matches(text, @"begin|try|except|end|case|uses|var|if|else|then");

            foreach (Match match in matchs)
            {
                TextPointer start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index);
                TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Length);

                TextRange textrange = new TextRange(start, end);
                ranges.Add(textrange);
            }
        }
        position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }
    foreach (TextRange range in ranges)
    {
        range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.CadetBlue));
        range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex is not very fast - how would it be to use a tokenizer and scan the text first and then apply the highlighting rules?

Comment: You could try profiling the code using a C# profiler. This should be able tell you how long each line is taking. Trying to improve performance without a profiler is like trying to pick the most scenic route whilst wearing a blindfold.

Comment: The function above does not work if a word has differently formatted parts. For example, when in the “**B**egin” word the first letter has the `Bold` style and the rest is the `Regular`.